# could not import fyne.io/fyne/v2/app (no required module provides package "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app")

Tags: go, google-developers-console, fyne

I am facing this issue while compiling the code, I don't know why this is happening because I have set GOPATH AND GOROOT in environmental variable.

[image]

Comment: Forget GOPATH and GOROOT. Use modules. In your project's root run `go mod init <module_path>` and then `go mod tidy`. If you read [getting started](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) you'll see there is no mention of GOROOT or GOPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do: `go get fyne.io/fyne/v2` to be able to import it in your code?
See Prerequisites in https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne for more information

Comment: To reiterate @mkopriva's comment on the original post, go mod tidy obviates this command.  Instead, you should `go mod tidy` to pull in - and record the versions of - the dependencies you pull in.